# WCF Service: How to find server logs to understand error?

Tags: c#, wcf

I know this is probably a pretty basic question but I am brand new to WCF and Service creation. I am running a local hosted WCF service using Microsoft VS 2010 C#4. I am trying to run the service through the URL through simple binding and running the PUT and GET methods through the URL. I am getting the:

. See server logs for more details.

error when I try to make a service request. How can I find these server logs?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Logging is not necessarily turned on. Tracing and logging need to be enabled in WCF configuration (app.config or web.config).
You can do this manually, or by clicking app.config and then selecting **Edit WCF Configuration**. If this item doesnt appear in context menu (happens in old versions of VS), you can find it in VS Tools menu or by running it manually (**SvcConfigEditor.exe**).

By default, messages are logged to files in directory from which application is ran. You can edit this in configuration editor once you enable logging. Editor will allow you to specify file path once you enable logging or tracing.

[image: WCF Configuration Editor]

You can later use Microsoft Service Trace Viewer tool for going through the files, as large XMLs and are not user friendly. Viewer tool should come up itself once you double click log files, or you can run it manually (**SvcTraceViewer.exe**).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Someone then showed WCF Test Client which made it much easier

Comment: Yes, **WcfTestClient.exe** is super cool tool. It's can also help with web services created without WCF.

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević, would tracing log if an IIS hosted WCF service is failing to host for some error? 
I did try adding log in the web.config - it displays that service is unavailable error - but no record as why the service failed for hosting the address itself? Should it have been logged?

Answer (score 18):

Add this to your web.config. you specify where the log goes in the initializeData attribute of the tracelistener

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\Temp\SvcLog\Traces.svclog" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Can I see the response XML that the service sends? I couldn't see it in the log file

Comment: I had to manually create the directory structure for the service to be able to create the log file.